# jekyll markdown bullet point issue

Tags: jekyll

I am editing my markdown in some online editor dillinger.io. Then copying the content into jekyll _posts. However, the jekyll is rendering on the browser differently that what I am seeing in above mentioned editor/github preview of the file.
The major problem I am facing is with the bullet points. I am not able to display bullet points with "*" or "-" markdown syntax. To display it using jekyll I need to use

tag in markdown file. I have googled for long hours and used below configuration in _config.yml file to get the better output.

> markdown: kramdown
>   kramdown:
>   input:          GFM

But still it is not the one I am expecting. Below are the screenshots

> Online editor and github preview are same as shown in the following URL -

[image]

> But Jekyll is rendering as follows -

[image]

> With the mentioned change in _config.yml file. It is better but still it does not display bullet points properly -

[image]

Some of the stackoverflow posts is saying that it is the issue with the default Jekyll markdown rendering engine.
Can you please suggest me what change do I need to make to get the same output as I see in github preview as mentioned in the following URL? -

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The kramdown GFM parser only supports some Github Flavored Markdown options ([see documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/parser/gfm.html))

In Jekyll you need `two new lines` before your list :

```
The list

- item 1
- item 2
```